# How to get text from textfield tag in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am creating text fields dynamically and each text field has tag.Now, I am trying to get text of textfield using that tags but, it returning UIButton and my application getting crashed.How can i get text from tags? please help me.
Here is my code to get text :

```
UITextField *textValue = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag];
NSString *chkText = textValue.text;

NSLog(@"entered Text %@",chkText);
```

my application is crashing at this line :

```
NSString *chkText = textValue.text;
```

and error is :
    -[UIButton text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: May be your textField tag is conflicting with uibutton.

Comment: u were assign the same tag in textfield and unbutton

Comment: You have to check the tags assigned and make sure tags are unique for UI elements.

Comment: Please check your UIButton and UITextField tags are same and because of it throughs this error, Change your textFiled tag as other and then check.

Comment: Why u r using textField.tag value if you have the textField referenece you can directly use it.
Getting the ref of textField using tag value and this tag value is obtained from textField ref. Why??

Comment: what does `NSLog(@"Tag: %d", textField.tag);` yield? I bet it's `0`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is your view contains button as well. So when you are trying to access it. It is returning UIButton object. So it is always better that check the condition whether it is button type or textfield type object. Try below:-

```
id nextTextField = [self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag];
nextTextField=([nextTextField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) ? nextTextField.text : nextTextField.title;
NSLog(@"%@", nextTextField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set textfield tag as any unique value like "346". (Avoid using 0 as tag value). And Use this --

```
UITextField *textValue = nil; 
id myObj = [self.view viewWithTag:yourTagValue];
if([myObj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
{
   textValue = (UITextField*)myObj; 
   NSString *chkText = textValue.text;
   NSLog(@"entered Text %@",chkText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code (`viewWithTag:textField.tag`), If you can access your `textField` then why are you accessing it once more? However, the below description will help you

You have assigned the **same tag to one of your UIButton control** in the same view. Also make sure that `textField.tag` is **greater than Zero**.

The below code will fix the crash, however, it will not resolve your issue.

```
UITextField *textFeild = [[self.view viewWithTag:textFieldTag] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]?(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textFieldTag]:nil;

if(nil != textFeild)
{
   NSString *chkText = textFeild.text;
   NSLog(@"entered Text %@",chkText);
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"textFeild is null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use tag, using NS_ENUM is a good habit.

```
NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TEST_TAGS)
{
    TAG_TEXT_INPUT,
    TAG_BTN_GO,
};
```

Then you can use it.

```
[textField setTag:TAG_TEXT_INPUT];
```

Comment: and since the first value in an enum is 0 `[view viewWithTag: TAG_TEXT_INPUT]` will return the first view that does not have a tag. Which is not necessarily the textField.

Comment: That's true. To avoid this, you can set the first value 1. Easy?

Answer (score 0):

First check to which UIVIew you are adding this textfield as a subview.

Take that UIVIew instance and call  viewWithTag method then your code works.